# Get column names in single row - DataFrame pivot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame which looks like this

| cola | colb | MeasureName | MeasureValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | Val1 | Count |
| 1 | 1 | Val1 | Total |
| 2 | 1 | Val1 | Average |
| 3 | 2 | Val2 | Count |
| 4 | 2 | Val2 | Total |
| 5 | 2 | Val2 | Average |

and when I pivot this table, it becomes like this

| MeasureName | Average | Count | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **cola** | **colb** |  |  |
| 1 | Val1 | 100 | 10 |
| 2 | Val2 | 10 | 5 |

But what I wanted is to have column names in single header row like below. How can I achive this please?

| cola | colb | Average | Count | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Val1 | 100 | 10 | 1000 |
| 2 | Val2 | 10 | 5 | 100 |

python code I use is below

```
d = {'cola':[1,1,1,2,2,2],'colb':['Val1','Val1','Val1','Val2','Val2','Val2'],'MeasureName':['Count','Total','Average','Count','Total','Average'],'MeasureValue':[10,1000,100,5,100,10]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d)
df1 = df1.pivot_table(index=["cola","colb"],columns="MeasureName",values="MeasureValue", aggfunc='first')
print(df1)
```

Comment: `df1 = df1.reset_index().rename_axis(columns =None)`

Comment: @Nk03 Thanks. I am getting "rename_axis() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'". I think it might be due to older version I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an older version, you can use:

```
df1.columns.name = None  # alternative to rename_axis
df1 = df1.reset_index()
```

```
>>> df1
   cola  colb  Average  Count  Total
0     1  Val1      100     10   1000
1     2  Val2       10      5    100
```